# Parsing JSON in Kotlin Multiplatform : io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input

Tags: json, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am taking my first look at Kotlin Multiplatform and am following the guide here

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-upgrade-app.html

I have my class

```
@Serializable
data class RocketLaunch (
    @SerialName("flight_number")
    val flightNumber: Int,
    @SerialName("name")
    val missionName: String,
    @SerialName("date_utc")
    val launchDateUTC: String,
    @SerialName("success")
    val launchSuccess: Boolean?,
)
```

I instantiate a HTTPClient and call the SpaceX URL as detailed in the guide

```
private val httpClient = HttpClient {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    suspend fun greet(): String {
        val rockets: List<RocketLaunch> = httpClient.get("https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches").body()
        val lastSuccessLaunch = rockets.first() //{ it.launchSuccess == true }
        return "Guess what it is! > ${platform.name.reversed()}!"
                "\nThe last successful launch was ${lastSuccessLaunch.title} "
    }
```

And when I run it and catch the exception I get

> kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected
> class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject (Kotlin reflection is not
> available) as the serialized body of
> kotlinx.serialization.Polymorphic, but had class
> kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonArray (Kotlin reflection is not
> available)

I have double checked and I am following the guide properly, and the feed works

**Plugin**

kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"

**Dependancies**

implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")

implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")

implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")

implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")

Comment: shouldn't it be `rockets: List<RocketLaunch>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to add

**id("kotlinx-serialization")** e.g.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}
```

To the shared build.gradle.kts file.  I find this odd as it was added to the Project level one as shown below.

**kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"**

Comment: I get this error: `UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'kotlinx-serialization'] was not found in any of the following sources`. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using version catalog

```
[versions]
kotlin = "1.9.21"
ktor = "2.3.7"

[libraries]
ktor-client-content-negotiation = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json", version.ref = "ktor" }

[plugins]
kotlinxSerialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error, what I did was to change `kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"` to `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"` in shared build.gradle.kts, and the problem was solved.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.21"
}
```